# Not able to connect to home internet after using limited wifi

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, router, internet, windows-10-preview

Problem: if I connect my Dell XPS or MacBook Pro to a limited WLAN e.g. on the train (where I need to accept the Terms of Use, and then I get internet access), and then later on I connect it to my home wifi with internet access, I'm able to connect to the WLAN, but I cannot use the internet - even if restart the network adapter / services couple of times. At the end only the restart of Windows 10 or Mac OS X High Sierra helps.

My very first question is, what is the name of this technology, which limits the internet of a WLAN to those who accepted the ToS in advance on an internal webpage?

How can I get by with this network issue?

Update 3rd June '18: CaptiveAgents in the background might have a role in manipulating the DNS, as pythonian mentioned it in the comment:
[Screenshot of Activity Monitor with the captiveagent in the process list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwNsG.png)

Comment: It's called "Captive Portal" or "Webpage Redirect".  They may be messing with your DNS address.  See if you can clear the DNS address and add googles DNS of 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4

Comment: cool, thanks for your answer! I'll try it next time. Do you also think that DNS flush or similar would solve the problem?

Comment: If your Router/DHCP server at home hands out DNS addresses, then yes, a DNS flush will force the laptop to obtain a DNS address from your router/DHCP server.

Comment: One step further, but still not at the end: I tried some internet tutorials for DNS client restart, but those were with killing some processes desperately during I turned off the WiFi. It fixed the problem without restarting the Mac OS. Now I'm researching how to restart the DNS elegantly - perharps with launchctl.